# Html Code in the velocity Template

Tags: velocity

```
I want to use the below velocity template in the format of html code. I had wroteen the above template into the html template.But in mail it displays as it is.

 Welcome $firstName $lastName! 
Please use activation code to activate your my fashions account Activation Code:$activationCode Please click the below link to activate your my fashions account. URl: $activationLink 

<html> 
<body>
 <h2> Welcome $firstName $lastName! </h2> 
<br> <br>
 Please use activation code to activate your my fashions account
```

**Activation Code:** $activationCode
      **Please click the below link to activate your my fashions account.**  Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully got the concept of the question, but try this:

```
`<html>`

`<body>`

    `<h2>Welcome ${first.userName}, ${last.lastname} </h2>`

`</html>`
```

I hope that helps

Comment: See this link at 22.3.2.1 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/mail.html